# grpc compile error about abseil-cpp “I no found"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, grpc, abseil

I want to compile grpc in arm linux. After downloading the github file and transfering to server, I cd grpc and make. It shows error about abseil-cpp, but when entering abseil-cpp directory and compiling, it competely ok.

Every time I compile the whole grpc, it always crash.

The error show it is about syntax error, but I think it is correctly syntax.

please help！

```
third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/variant.h:509:7:   required by substitution of ‘template<class T, long unsigned int I, class Tj, absl::lts_20220623::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Tj, T>::value, void>* <anonymous> > constexpr absl::lts_20220623::variant<grpc_core::Pending, grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<grpc_core::ReclaimerQueue::Handle> >::variant(T&&) [with T = absl::lts_20220623::variant<grpc_core::Pending, grpc_core::RefCountedPtr<grpc_core::ReclaimerQueue::Handle> >; long unsigned int I = <missing>; Tj = <missing>; absl::lts_20220623::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Tj, T>::value, void>* <anonymous> = <missing>]’
./src/core/lib/resource_quota/memory_quota.h:211:72:   required from here
third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/types/variant.h:509:7: internal compiler error: unexpected expression ‘I’ of kind template_parm_index
       class Tj = absl::variant_alternative_t<I, variant>,
       ^~~~~
```

```cpp
template <
    class T,
    std::size_t I = std::enable_if<
        variant_internal::IsNeitherSelfNorInPlace<variant,
                                                  absl::decay_t<T>>::value,
        variant_internal::IndexOfConstructedType<variant, T>>::type::value,
    class Tj = absl::variant_alternative_t<I, variant>,
    absl::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<Tj, T>::value>* =
        nullptr>
constexpr variant(T&& t) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible<Tj, T>::value)
    : Base(variant_internal::EmplaceTag<I>(), absl::forward<T>(t)) {}
```

Comment: Assuming you use GCC to build, what version of GCC are you using?

Comment: gcc (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-6)

Comment: That's a rather old version of GCC. It's possibly a bug in the compiler. Try install different versions of GCC and check against them. Also try with different compilers (like ICC or Clang) if available for your old RedHat distribution.

Comment: oh, I update the gcc, the problem change. new problem come out.

Comment: ```In file included from /data/herry/isulad/gitGRPC/src/core/lib/iomgr/sockaddr_utils_posix.cc:29:
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:135:2: error: ‘u32’ does not name a type
  135 |  u32 real_ip;
      |  ^~~
/usr/include/linux/tcp.h:136:2: error: ‘u16’ does not name a type
  136 |  u16 real_port;
      |  ^~~```

Comment: I solve it by change u16 to __u16 and it pass